# Нужен конструктор для построения из HTML тегов в JQuery код

Tags: html, jquery

Не спрашивайте для чего, ибо это может показаться странно и зачем это.
К примеру есть большая страница с html тегами:

```
<body>
    <p class="myclass">
        <b style="color:yellow;font-size:20px;">Hello</b>
        <b>World</b>
    </p>
</body>
```

Нужно прогнать через требуемый конструктор/форматтер чтоб получилось:

```
$('body').append(
    $('<p>').addClass('myclass').append(
        $('<b>').css('color','yellow').css('font-size','20px').text('Hello')
    ).append(
        $('<b>').text('World')
    )
);
```

Есть ли такой конструктор где-нибудь?

Comment: Почему бы просто не применить какой-нибудь шаблонизатор?

Comment: таки все-таки: для чего и зачем?

Comment: Этот "конструктор" называют **шаблонизатором**. Возьмите что-то типа Handlebars и будет Вам `JS` функция, создающая этот HTML. Правда использование шаблонов в фронтэнде должно быть оправдано, а не просто "быть в тренде".

Comment: andreymal, @Other спасибо узнал много нового, но увы это не подходит в данном случае, мне нужно не https://habrastorage.org/getpro/habr/post_images/885/1f2/9ab/8851f29abdc10bafd3bea2e723da2a61.png, а именно что я описал, надеялся есть подобное что то, ладно напишу подобный "конструктор" сам.

Comment: Проще простого. Пишите/берёте добротный модульный парсер HTML и добавляете модуль, который будет рендерить результат оборачивая токены в нужный... вкус и цвет. Когда-то я подобное к шаблонизатору `Twig` писал, думаю, на `JS` что-то подобное есть.

Answer (score 1):

Написал на PHP на скорую руку, вдруг кому пригодится. Конечно учтены не все тонкости, но основной геморой автоматизируется, а остальные недочеты правятся ручками:
Библиотеку для парсинга HTML брать отсюда: http://jquery.hohli.com/

```
<?php
include('phpQuery.php');
$document = phpQuery::newDocument(file_get_contents('html.txt'));
function parse($document){
    function process($element,$t){
        $t++;
        $tagName = $element->{'tagName'};
        $tagText = $element->{'textContent'};
        $tagAttrs_arr = pq($element)->attr('*');
        $tagAttrs = '';
        foreach($tagAttrs_arr as $p=>$v){
            switch($p){
                case 'class':
                    $classes_arr = explode(' ',$v);
                    foreach($classes_arr as $v){$tagAttrs.= $v!=''?".addClass('$v')":'';}
                    break;
                default:
                    $tagAttrs.= ".attr('".addslashes($p)."','".addslashes($v)."')";
            }
        }
        $result = '$(\'<'.$tagName.'>\')'.$tagAttrs;
        $result.= $tagText!=''?(count(pq($element)->children())==0?'.text(\''.$tagText.'\')':''):'';
        foreach(pq($element)->children() as $child){
            $result.= ".append(\r\n";
            for($i=0;$i<$t;$i++){$result.="\t";}
            $result.= process($child,$t)."\r\n";
            for($i=0;$i<$t-1;$i++){$result.="\t";}
            $result.=')';
        }
        return $result;
    }
    $t = 1;
    $result = '';
    foreach($document->children() as $element){
        for($i=0;$i<$t;$i++){$result.="\t";}
        $result.=process($element,$t);
    }
    return $result;
}
echo(parse($document));
?>
```